# How can I hide the API calls that a c# app makes?

Tags: c#, api, winapi, apimonitor

I want to hide Api calls which is used in my c# program from the programs like [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).    (Windows)
whether packers can do this?
I search about this alot but i cant find any thing that can help .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: You almost certainly can't. Packers will generally let you hide the imports, but they can be detected by watching your LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress calls. But things that monitor what you actually call in your app can't be fooled without e.g. inlining kernel interrupts in your own code and you don't want to start going there - and if you really do then C# is the wrong place to start. Why? Do you want to do something malicious?

Comment: In which case you should study some viruses to see how they disguise their API calls, and do it that way. Reimplementing it won't help you at all, since you won't be testing techniques used by viruses.

Comment: My guess is that Api Monitor requires administrator privileges to run. So maybe block your application in such case ?????

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of doing this? What exactly is `antivirus works`?

Answer (score -2):

You basically bake VPN code into your app.

Make a connection to anywhere in your country, perhaps a list that your code picks one at random each time the app is loaded.

Then when the app makes the calls there all encrypted by the vpn.

For a website you can use Azure or AWS with something like Cloudflare.

Comment: This addresses a type of APIs different from what the question characterised referring to rohitab.com *API Monitor*.